Can a foaming hand dispenser whip cream?
These look like simple hand soap dispensers. They do a good job of converting liquid soap into a light, fluffy foam.
If filled with cream, would they dispense whipped cream? Or is cream not bubbly enough?

Those dispensers inject large (a millimeter or more) bubbles of air into liquid hand soap, a fluid which is known for foaming. Cream doesn’t have the same properties. Bubbles that large will float right back out.
Whipped cream dispensers work quite similarly, but with gas injected at a higher pressure through a smaller nozzle, leading to much smaller bubbles which the cream can hold and form a foam with.
